# Apache Hive - cannot interpret output

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

I am running a HIVE query from my Java Program . I got the output fine and looking at the Hive command console i am confused at the following HDFS Read and HDFS write statistics .

```
Query ID = user_20151125192730_ccab28bb-830d-4ff0-9231-fe7405795d4f
Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks not specified. Estimated from input data size: 4
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapreduce.job.reduces=<number>
Job running in-process (local Hadoop)
2015-11-25 19:27:31,849 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2015-11-25 19:27:35,879 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%
2015-11-25 19:27:41,996 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%
Ended Job = job_local1955981114_0014
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Stage-Stage-1:  HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 SUCCESS
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec
```

Why is the HDFS Read and HDFS Write zero bytes and also the CPU time spent 0 msec.

I am using hive 1.2.1 and Hadoop 2.6 in a single node mode.

Comment: It may be that you're reading the file from your local FS, you can see that from a DESCRIBE EXTENDED for the table you're querying.

Comment: You are totally right . I was reading from local file system . I copied the file to HDFS using the hadoop  fs -put <loca path> <hdfs path>. The problem i am having i am not able to find out the full HDFS path as is relates to my file system to give it in LOAD command  like below.  LOAD DATA IN PATH (<full HDFS path of the file , not the relative path above> ) . This is my first dip at Hadoop and Hive.

Comment: Was finally able to solve the HDFS Read and Write by reading from HDFS as supposed to local FS.  Why CPU time is still 0 msec seems puzzling. Plz see below . Any pointer? Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 1; number of reducers: 1
2015-11-29 23:18:20,219 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2015-11-29 23:18:25,344 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%
2015-11-29 23:18:30,472 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%
Ended Job = job_1448857017878_0002
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Stage-Stage-1: Map: 1  Reduce: 1   HDFS Read: 8016880 HDFS Write: 156 SUCCESS
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec